# Google marker is not being displayed on map

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have written code to display a marker on a googlemap. The code is copied almost verbatim, from the Google API docs. Yet the marker is not displaying on the page.

Here is my code: What am I doing wrong?

```js
var map;
var central_location = new google.maps.LatLng(42.745334, 12.738430);

function initialize() {
  var mapCanvas = document.getElementById('map');
  var mapOptions = {
    center: central_location,
    zoom: 14,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  }
  map = new google.maps.Map(mapCanvas, mapOptions);

}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

$(document).ready(function() {
  var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
    content: '<div>Hello</div>'
  });

  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: central_location,
    map: map,
    title: 'This is the title'
  });

  marker.addListener('click', function() {
    infowindow.open(map, marker);
  });

  marker.setMap(map);

});
```

```css
#map {
  width: 500px;
  height: 380px;
}
```

```html
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript" style=""></script>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>

<div id="map"></div>
```

I notice that there are similar questions, the only thing that seems to be  different with my question is that I am creating my marker in the jQuery ready() event - NOT the initialize() function.

Is this why the marker is not been displayed?

Note: I don't remember reading anything in the Google API docs that states that markers should be created when the map is being created, so that can't obviously be the case

Comment: why you dont move the entire the code inside the doc ready function?

Comment: @Vanojx1: I was thinking of doing that ;)  But I thought that having the script run in the header will avoid the problem of the page being displayed without a map being visible

Comment: @Vanojx1: I just tried what you suggested (i,e. moving all the code into the document ready function), and the marker was still not displayed...

Comment: Ofc look at @Rejith solution.... its correct to initialize the entire map ( with markers and infowindow ) inside the initialize function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move your marker creation to the `initialize` function.

`$(document).ready(function(){})` works when DOM elements are loaded, which doesn't necessarily mean that the map is loaded. So if you try to create the marker in the document ready function, the map might not be created then, once the map is ready `map`  variable has the map object, so you can make the marker on that, and you can add the markers dynamically after the map is loaded.

```js
var map;
var central_location = new google.maps.LatLng(42.745334, 12.738430);
function initialize() {
  console.log('map loaded');
  var mapCanvas = document.getElementById('map');
  var mapOptions = {
    center: central_location,
    zoom: 14,
    streetViewControl: false,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  }
  map = new google.maps.Map(mapCanvas, mapOptions);
  makePin(42.745334, 12.738430);
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

$(document).ready(function(){
  console.log('document loaded');
})

function makePin(lat, long){
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(lat, long),
    map: map,
    title: 'This is the title'
  });
  var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
    content: '<div>Hello</div>'
  });
  marker.addListener('click', function() {
    infowindow.open(map, marker);
  });
}
```

```css
#map {
  width: 500px;
  height: 380px;
}
```

```html
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript" style=""></script>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
   
<button onclick="makePin(42.749334, 12.739430)">Add Pin</button>
<div id="map"></div>
```

Comment: I don't like this solution, because `initialize` gets called once, and it means I can't dynamically add markers to the map (that's essentially, what I'm trying to do).

Comment: @HomunculusReticulli You can make a function to create new pins which can create pins on the map. See the updated answer.

Comment: @HomunculusReticulli  I created a function `makePin` and  `makePin(42.749334, 12.739430)` adds new pin.

Comment: Ok, thanks, this now does what I want it to do. In order to learn from it though (and accept your answer), could you please explain to me what I was doing wrong, and how/why your solution fixes that. Thanks

Comment: @HomunculusReticulli  `$(document).ready(function(){})` works when DOM elements are loaded, which doesn't necessarily mean that the map is loaded. So if you try to create the marker in the document ready function, the map might not be created then, once the map is ready `map`  variable has the map object, so you can make the marker on that, and you can add the markers dynamically after the map is loaded.

Answer (score 1):

How can you make marker without loaded map. Map need to initialize first then marker will work

```
function initialize() {
                    var mapCanvas = document.getElementById('map');
                    var mapOptions = {
                                          center: central_location,
                                          zoom: 14,
                                          streetViewControl: false,
                                          mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
                                     }
                    map = new google.maps.Map(mapCanvas, mapOptions);

                    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                        position: central_location,
                        map: map,
                        title: 'This is the title'
                    });

                    marker.addListener('click', function () {
                        infowindow.open(map, marker);
                    });

                    marker.setMap(map);
             }
```

Comment: I don't  understand your comment. The marker is being created in the jQuery ready() event. By the time that event is fired, the map would have been created already, since the initialize function is in the head section of the page.

Comment: Map is always undefined

Comment: Not true... An exception would have been thrown if this was the case

Comment: You can check it using console.log or Alert

Comment: @Homunculus Reticulli: `$.ready` (domready) fires **before** `window.onload`

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution:

```js
var map;
var central_location = new google.maps.LatLng(42.745334, 12.738430);

function initialize() {
  var mapCanvas = document.getElementById('map');
  var mapOptions = {
    center: central_location,
    zoom: 14,
    streetViewControl: false,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  }
  map = new google.maps.Map(mapCanvas, mapOptions);
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: central_location,
    map: map,
    title: 'This is the title'
  });

  marker.addListener('click', function() {
    infowindow.open(map, marker);
  });

  marker.setMap(map);

}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

$(document).ready(function() {
  var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
    content: '<div>Hello</div>'
  });

});
```

```css
#map {
  width: 500px;
  height: 380px;
}
```

```html
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript" style=""></script>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>

<div id="map"></div>
```